# Files missing from Repos in Databricks

Tags: databricks, databricks-repos

I have an issue with files disappearing from Databricks Repos.

- The files exist in the branch in git locally and in the git web platform
- I have pulled the latest version of the branch into Databricks Repos.

Yet some of the files do not exist in the Databricks Repos.  Some of the files re-appeared and then disappeared again after pulling.

A somewhat vague question, but any idea why all files in the remote git branch do not appear in the Databricks Repos after pulling?

Comment: do you have files in repos enabled?

Comment: If your files are Non-Notebook please refer to this documentation 

https://docs.databricks.com/repos/index.html#work-with-non-notebook-files-in-a-databricks-repo

Comment: @AlexOtt, yes I have files in Repos enabled.  Some more details: I deleted the repo from databricks and then all of the files re-appeared.  I then made a change to one of the files in databricks - then commit + pushed through databricks.  After this, many of the files did not appear ... or appeared in the wrong directory.

Comment: Ok. Let me get this to developers - you may need to open a support ticket

Comment: I pointed developers to this question, and they are asking to file a support ticket to be able to look into logs, etc.

Comment: Is there any resolution yet on this issue? I'm having the same problem